# Print media query for header and footer

Tags: css, printing

I have a react application with header and footer component and home component, that a client would like to print home page content, and the part I'm having trouble getting my head around is to get the header and footer appears on every page.i want hiding header on all but first page and footer on all but last .  any print media query for that??

Comment: It is really hard to understand your problem, could you give some details? Also, not sure if it is `reactjs` related problem.

Comment: header and footer are repeated in every page when i press ctrl+p print command from chrome ,i want to prevent header and footer from all page ;should only show for  first page and last page page